# Balancing fight script in Text Based Javascript Game

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery

I'm working on a little text based javascript game and I've been using chromes Javascript console for the output. The 'game' works off a series of methods written into an object called `Player` created from a constructor `Character` that are linked to HTML buttons and manipulated with jQuery 1.11.

The code has been validated by multiple sources to be 100% clean JS however, we all know that doesn't always matter. There are a number of bugs i've found that I can't find a solution to.

The two biggest bugs i've noticed:

- certain instances of enemies will spawn with zero health when as far as I can tell i've made there health to a minimum of 1
- After a number of battles the player automatically wins every time with 1 hit.

I've included a JSFiddle to hopefully give you an idea of the working code although, you won't see output due to the fact it is all returned in the console.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/vxbp7fxL/5/)

Any and all help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

**Note:** In the the script, the buttons, `explore` and `run` aren't linked to anything. The way to trigger the fights is to `rest` and an enemy will randomly come and there attributes will be loaded into the div `enemy`. The 'Fight Log' is logged to the console.

Here are is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var m = Math;
    //function in Character constructor
    function do_dmg(enemy) {
        //calculates amount of damage done by by finding the lower number between a (rand int from 0 to personal health - a rand int from 0 to enemy health) and
        var dmg = m.min(m.max(
        m.round(m.random() * this.health) - m.round(m.random() * enemy.health), 0),
        enemy.health);
        $('#hp').text(this.health);
        $('#ehp').text(enemy.health -= dmg);
        if (dmg === 0) {
            console.log(this.name + " evades " + enemy.name + "'s attack!");
        } else {
            console.log(this.name + " hurts " + enemy.name + " for " + dmg);
            return enemy.health <= 0;
        }
    }
}

//Methods from Player Object.
p.rest = function () {
    console.log(this.awoken);
    if (this.awoken === 0) {
        window.enemy = Enemies[m.floor(m.random() * Enemies.length)];
        window.enemy = enemy;
        console.log(this.name + ' is awoken by a ' + enemy.name + '!');
        $('#ename').text(enemy.name);
        $('#ehp').text(enemy.health);
        this.state = 'fight';
        $('#state').text(this.state);
        this.enemy_atk();

    } else if (this.awoken == 1) {
        console.log(this.name + ' rests.');
        if (this.health < this.max_health) {
            this.health += 1;
            $('#hp').text(p.health);
        } else if (this.energy < this.max_energy) {
            this.energy += 1;
            $('#ep').text(p.energy);
        } else {
            console.log(this.name + ' slept too long.');
            this.energy -= 1;
            $('#ep').text(p.energy);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(this.name + 'can\'t rest right now');
    }

},

p.enemy_atk = function () {
    if (enemy.health >= 1) {
        if (enemy.do_dmg(this) >= this.health) {
            this.health = 0;
            console.log(this.name + ' was killed by the ' + enemy.name);
        } else {
            $('#ehp').text(enemy.health);
            $('#hp').text(this.health);
        }
    } else {
        $('#ename').text('');
        $('#ehp').text('');
        console.log(this.name + ' killed the ' + enemy.name);
        console.log(this.name + ' gained ' + enemy.XP / this.level + ' EXP!');
        this.state = 'normal';
        $('#state').text(this.state);
    }


},

p.atk = function () {
    if (this.state != 'fight') {
        console.log(this.name + ' swings at nothing and falls.');
        this.tired();
    } else {
        if (this.do_dmg(enemy) >= enemy.health) {
            enemy.health = 0;
            console.log(this.name + ' killed ' + enemy.name);
            console.log(this.name + ' gained ' + enemy.XP / this.level + ' EXP!');
            $('#ename').text('');
            $('#ehp').text('');
            this.state = 'normal';
            $('#state').text(this.state);
        } else {
            this.do_dmg(enemy);
            this.enemy_atk();
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: This is the kind of issue i would solve by re-designing the code : Have clear objects with defined responsabilities, and de-correlate the codes handling 1) the input / 2) the game / 3) and especially the output.!! Clarify !! I started a bit here : http://jsfiddle.net/vxbp7fxL/6/